# $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, satisfying

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, satisfying

$$p(x)=2-q(x);\quad for\quad 0<x<1$$

find $P(X<-1)+P(Y<2)$.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

$P(X<-1)+P(Y<2)$

$=0+P(Y<2)$

$=\int_{-\infty}^2 q(x)dx$

$=\int_{-\infty}^2 [2-p(x)]dx$

$=\int_0^2 [2-p(x)]dx$

$=\int_0^1 [2-p(x)]dx +\int_1^2 [2-p(x)]dx$

$=\int_0^1 [2-p(x)]dx+0$

$=[2x]_0^1-\int_0^1 p(x)dx$

$=(2-0)-1$

$=1$

*Is it correct?*

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where $p,q$ are taken to be nonzero in your problem setup; assuming $0<X<1$ you're correct though a couple of your steps (like $\int 2-p$ from -infinity to 0 vanishing) are not quite right.

More straightforwardly, notice that if $0<X<1$ then integrating the relation given we find $\int_0^1 q = 2-1=1$ and so $Y\in [0,1]$ with probability one.